# MongoDB: How to compare Single Document Element (not Array)

Tags: mongodb

I'm new in MongoDB. I try to switch from MySQL to MongoDB.
I have problem that, I don't know how to compare Collection Element with Input value.
So far, I read all the Collection and compare the following paragraph is my code.
I wonder whether we can have efficient way to do.

```
var Database = objMongoClient.GetDatabase("MachineLog");

        IMongoCollection<Machine> MachineCollection;
        MachineCollection = Database.GetCollection<Machine>("machine");
        var Machines = MachineCollection.AsQueryable<Machine>().ToList();

        foreach (var Machine in Machines)
        {
            if (**strMachineID == Machine.MachineID.ToString() && Machine.MachineType.ToString() == "Host"**)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("id:" + Machine.Id.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("MachineID:" + Machine.MachineID.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("MachineType:" + Machine.MachineType.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("OriginalFileLocation:" + Machine.OriginalFileLocation.ToString());
                strDirectory = Machine.OriginalFileLocation.ToString();
            }
        }
```

If you have any another way to do, would you like to share with me?
Thank you.

Comment: Something like `var Machines = MachineCollection.AsQueryable<Machine>().Where(m.MachineID => "strMachineID " && x.MachineType == "Host").ToList();`

Comment: Hi Verram,
Thank you for your help.
I have a question is, why is x.MachineType? why don't we use m.MachineType?

FYI,
from your suggestion, here is my code:

`var Machines = MachineCollection.AsQueryable<Machine>().Where(p => p.MachineID == strMachineID && p.MachineType == "Host").ToList();`

Comment: Np. It was a typo. what you have now is right.

Comment: I see, Veeram. Thank you so much for your time and help.

Comment: Hi Veeram. I have another question is, how can I return objects that is sorted by "Date" field to List ?

Comment: Something like `var Machines = MachineCollection.AsQueryable<Machine>().Where(p => p.MachineID == strMachineID && p.MachineType == "Host").OrderBy(p=> p.Date).ToList()`

Comment: Thank you for your help, Veeram :)
It's like a magic.